# How to add object to prototype in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
class Classname {
    constructor(args) {
        // code
    }

    // this method is added to Classname.prototype
    function_name(argument) {
        // body...
    }

    //how to add objects similarly to prototype
}
```

Is there any way to add an object to Classname.prototype?

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve.  Adding an object to `Classname.prototype` will cause that object to be shared among all instances of your class which is usually not what you want.  But, if that's' what you want to do, you can just assign directly to the prototype: `Classname.prototype.somePropertyName = {greeting: "hello"};` after the definition of `Classname`.   ES6 prototypes work just like they did in ES5.  ES6 syntax is just sugar for setting up the prototype with nicer syntax.

Comment: ClassName.prototype.test={}

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: Why do you want another way? By the way, your `function function_name` syntax inside the class is incorrect.

Comment: If I want to add more than one object, I need assign each object by Classname.prototype.somePropertyName. Is there any way to add it in the class declaration?

Comment: You can use any way to add properties to an object. E.g. `Object.assign(Classname.prototype, {foo: {}, bar: {}, baz: {}})`. There is no specific syntax for this for classes.

Comment: @PranayKumar due to you lack of knowledge on how to do it, I'd doubt that you understand what you do when you add an object to some prototype (although @jfriend00 tried to explain it to you). So, long story short: **stop trying to extend the prototype, extend `this` in the `constructor()`**.

Comment: If you want to add an object as instance data, then just assign it in the constructor `this.somePropertyName = {greeting: "hello"};`.

Comment: @Thomas I want a shared Object. which will be common for all my instances of Classname

Comment: If you're sure about that, then it seems that I've misjudged the situation. Although I'd still discourage this approach. But this ain't the right place to start a conversation about pros and cons of different approaches/structures and about alternatives, especially with me knowing so little about your whole project. So I'd wish you good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can define properties on prototype inside class body using getters and setters. But this is kinda verbose.

For example.

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Shared'
}
class A {
  get a() {
    return obj
  }
}

const a1 = new A

console.log(A.prototype.hasOwnProperty('a'))
console.log(a1.hasOwnProperty('a'))
console.log(a1.a)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Classname.prototype.myObject = {};
```

Or

```
Classname.prototype.myObject = Object.assign({ foo: 'bar'}, { bar: 'baz' }, anotherObject)
```

For e.g.

```
const User = function() {};
User.prototype.info = Object.assign({ foo: 'bar' }, { bar: 'baz' });

const bob = new User();
bob.info; // => { foo: 'bar', bar: 'baz' }
```

Comment: Your examples are weird. Why do you set `Classname.prototype.myObject = {}` if you overwrite it in the very next line with `{ foo: 'bar'}`? And the `Object.assign()` in your second example is completely useless. `Object.assign({foo: 'bar'})` and `{foo: 'bar'}` are identical. The object is returned exactly as it is passed in to `Object.assign()`.

Comment: You're right. They are weird. Mostly because I didn't explain properly, or expand where I should have.